# R memoise on Linux server

Tags: r, linux, shiny, shiny-server, memoise

I'm testing memoise to cache a big dataframe in a R shiny application. It works totally fine on my local windows machine but as soon as I deploy the code on the Linux server, somehow it seems memoise doesn't do anything and every time I try to call the memoise function it takes it forever to load. Hence my question: is there a specific setting I need to change in order to efficiently run on a linux server?
Sample code (the real code loads a dataframe from a database and massage the data):

```
ui <- dashboardPage(  # https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html
    title = "Dashboard",  
    dashboardHeader(title = "Angelo's Board"),
    dashboardSidebar(   # inside here everything that is displayed on the left hand side
      includeCSS("www/styles.css"),    

      sidebarMenu(      

        menuItem('menu 1', tabName = "menu1", icon = icon("th"),
                 menuItem('Data 1', tabName = 'tab_data1'))

      )),


    dashboardBody( 

      tabItems(

        tabItem(tabName = 'tab_data1')),
      h3("Page with big table"),
      fluidRow(dataTableOutput("main_table"))
    ))


  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    func_create_df <- function(){
       df <- data.frame(names = c("Mark","George","Mary"), age = c(30,40,35))
       df
    }

    func_create_df_mem <- memoise(func_create_df, ~timeout(1))

    output$main_tabl <- renderDataTable({ 
      df <- func_create_df_mem()
    })

  }

  cat("\nLaunching   'shinyApp' ....")
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As a side, less important question, it seems the timeout feature described here (https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/02/02/memoise-1-0-0/) doesn't do anything as well.